# Android marketplace private applications for hardware exclusive?

Tags: android, google-play

We're working with a client who's planning on bundling their software on a new piece of hardware.

The app will be bundled on the internal memory and needs to be updateable but is device specific, it's a hardware exclusive app.

Ideally we'd like to use the marketplace as the update backbone but there don't seem to be any options for having a private application.

How is this normally done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post

http://groups.google.com/group/android-discuss/browse_thread/thread/7ab083cabe70e77c?pli=1

Comment: Thanks for this, good to know it's possible to run an installer yourself.

It's really not ideal to get users to turn on install unknown applications so if there's a more official way, that'd be great to hear about.